# How to calculate total length of process before it changes - in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

Here is a snippet of data-frame which looks like this (original data frame contains 8k rows):

```
  User          State      change_datetime        endstate
  ---------------------------------------------------------
   100234       XIM        2016-01-19 17:03:12    Inactive 
   100234       Active     2016-01-28 17:17:15    XIM
   100234       Active     2016-02-16 17:57:50    NaN
   100234       Live       2018-03-04 06:30:01    Active
   213421       XIM        2016-02-16 17:57:53    NaN
   213421       Active     2018-02-01 10:01:51    XIM
   213421       Active     2018-02-01 20:49:41    NaN
   213421       Active     2018-02-13 20:40:11    NaN
   213421       R          2018-03-04 05:38:51    Active
   612312       B-98       2018-11-01 17:12:11    XIM
```

I'm trying to find out how long each unique User spends in an 'Active' state till they change into a different state other than 'Active'. Is it possible to create a loop to generate a list indicating unique User and the length of time the User spent as 'Active' before changing state?

To calculate the length of time, I found the difference between the first 'change_datetime' where the User is in an 'Active' state between the last 'change_datetime' value for when User was last seen as 'Active'.

For example:
User '100234' spent: 19 days, 0 hours, 40 minutes and 35 seconds in 'Active' state

Thank you.

Comment: How do you calculate 40 days from user 100234?

Comment: I guess it's 20

Comment: @HenryYik So I manually calculated the difference between the 'change_datetime' for row 2 and 3 (where the state is Active) for User 100234 and that came up to 40 days and 40 minutes

Comment: @mathfux Hi, was just wondering what you mean about '20'?

Comment: I came up with 20 days and 40 minutes instead

Comment: You mean there are 40 days between `2016-02-16 17:57:50` and `2016-01-28 17:17:15`?

Comment: @mathfux yes you are right oops - however in this case the time has been involved so it would be 19 days and 40 mins (just for requirement purposes)

Comment: @HenryYik apologies, I muddled up the months. Should be 19 days and 40 minutes (according to the time length). Thanks

Comment: Is it always 1 session for 1 user? Can a user have 2nd active status after the first active streak?

Comment: @HenryYik Yes usually each unique User has one 'Active' state streak in this data set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always have one session only, you only need two conditions:

```
df["change_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["change_datetime"])

cond1 = df["State"].eq("Active")
cond2 = df["State"].shift(-1).ne("Active")

start = df.loc[cond1].groupby("User")["change_datetime"].first()
end = df.loc[cond1&cond2].groupby("User")["change_datetime"].first()

print (end-start)

User
100234   19 days 00:40:35
213421   12 days 10:38:20
Name: change_datetime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Is there a way I could print the output into a new dataframe?

Comment: Use `(end-start).to_frame()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have been very helpful :)

Comment: Please don't update the data requirements in an answered question - post as a new question with your new data and attempts instead.

Comment: apologies for that, I have created a new question for this now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559473/how-to-calculate-total-length-of-process-until-it-changes-using-two-columns-in-p