# How to calculate total length of process until it changes using two columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, date

Here is a snippet of data-frame which looks like this (original data frame contains 8k rows):

```
     User   State      change_datetime  endstate
0  100234     XIM  2016-01-19 17:03:12  Inactive
1  100234  Active  2016-01-28 17:17:15       XIM
2  100234  Active  2016-02-16 17:57:50       NaN
3  100234    Live  2016-02-16 17:58:51    Active
4  213421     XIM  2016-02-16 17:57:53       NaN
5  213421  Active  2018-02-01 10:01:51       XIM
6  213421  Active  2018-02-01 20:49:41       NaN
7  213421  Active  2018-02-13 20:40:11       NaN
8  213421       R  2018-03-04 05:38:51    Active
9  612312    B-98  2018-11-01 17:12:11       XIM
```

I'm trying to find out how long each unique User spends in an 'Active' state till they change into a different state other than 'Active'. There is an 'endstate' column which contains an 'Active' value, So I wanted to calculate the total time difference from when the 'State' column starts as 'Active' until the 'endstate' column contains 'Active'

Originally, I used the following code:

```
df["change_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["change_datetime"])

cond1 = df["State"].eq("Active")
cond2 = df["State"].shift(-1).ne("Active")

start = df.loc[cond1].groupby("User")["change_datetime"].first()
end = df.loc[cond1&cond2].groupby("User")["change_datetime"].first()

print (end-start)
Active_state_duration = (end-start).to_frame()
Active_state_duration.head()
```

The returned results are:

```
User
100234   19 days 00:40:35
213421   12 days 10:38:20
Name: change_datetime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

For User 100234, 19 days and 00:40:35 is calculated for Line 2 and 3 however it should be 19 days and 00:41:36 (using Line 4) as it takes the User 1 minute and 1 second to transition from 'Active' to 'Live'.

I was hoping to use the 'endstate' column in this code so that the time duration of the User being 'Active' is run using the 'State' column until the next line of code has 'Active' as the value in 'end_state' and a different value other than 'Active' for 'State'.
Here is an example of how i'm hoping to calculate the time duration:

Is there a way to do this?

Here is how i'm trying to calculate the duration:
[image]

Comment: I think the duration for the user `213421` should be `30 days 19:37:00`, right?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yes that is correct - This is how I would like to calculate the time duration of the User being Active as originally I only focused on the 'State' column however now I want to use the 'endstate' column where the value is 'Active' to calculate the total duration of each user being active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to create a boolean mask `m` then filter the dataframe using this mask and use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `agg` the column `change_datetime` using [`np.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html):

```
m = df['State'].eq('Active') | df['endstate'].eq('Active')
s = df[m].groupby(['User', (~m).cumsum()])['change_datetime'].agg(np.ptp).droplevel(1)
```

OR, if always need to consider one transition per user in the dataframe:

```
m1 = df['State'].eq('Active')
m2 = ~m1 & df['endstate'].eq('Active')

s1 = df[m1].groupby('User')['change_datetime'].first()
s2 = df[m2].groupby('User')['change_datetime'].first()

s = s2.sub(s1)
```

Result:

```
print(s)
User
100234   19 days 00:41:36
213421   30 days 19:37:00
Name: change_datetime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: I tried to run this however I get: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'droplevel'

Comment: Hmm. Can you try without using `droplevel`?

Comment: I removed the droplevel but now the output is: Series([], Name: dt_tim_change, dtype: float64) .. Ihe list of users are not printed along with time duration :(

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to reply to you :(

Comment: @RSem I think you should be able to chat you have 125 reputaion.

Comment: @Shubham Sharma nice answer +1, came up with something similar but couldn't just match `import numpy as np
df=(df.assign(endstate=(np.where(~(df.endstate=='Active')|(df.endstate.isna()),np.nan,df.endstate))))`
df.endstate=df.endstate.combine_first(df.State)
df[(df.endstate=='Active')].groupby('User')['change_datetime'].agg(np.ptp)